# Force memory allocation to allocate from higher address (>4GB) on 64-bit Linux

Tags: c++, linux, memory-management, 64-bit, x86-64

Here're what I want to do:
I have a library built for 64-bit Linux.
Then I created an application linking that library.
I want to make sure when I run the application, the memory allocated from the library is always in the higher location (>4GB).

On Windows, user can force allocations to allocate from higher addresses before lower addresses for testing purposes, specify MEM_TOP_DOWN when calling VirtualAlloc or set the following registry value to 0x100000:

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Memory Management\AllocationPreference

I wonder if there's similar strategy on Linux. I understand the Linux memory management is different than Window, but I found some clue such as using mmap() or linker scripts. But I haven't been able to achieve the goal. Anybody could provide more information?

```
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#define handle_error(msg) \
  do { perror(msg); exit(EXIT_FAILURE); } while (0)

int main()
{
  void *addr1=0, *addr2=0;
  long sz = sysconf(_SC_PAGE_SIZE); // get page size
  size_t length = sz*1000*1000; // 1,000,000 pages
  int fd = -1;

  printf("page size = %ld\n", sz);

  // find some available address
  int *p = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int));
  long start = (long)p + sizeof(int);
  free(p); // free it anyway

  start += (sz-(start % sz)); // page alignment
  printf("start = 0x%lx\n", start);

  // mmap fixed
  addr1 = mmap((void*)start, length, PROT_NONE,
               MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_NORESERVE|MAP_ANONYMOUS|MAP_FIXED, fd, 0);
  if (addr1 == MAP_FAILED)
    handle_error("mmap");
  printf("first map: %tx\n", addr1);
  //msync(addr1, length, 0);

  // another mmap
  addr2 = mmap(NULL, sz*10, PROT_NONE,
               MAP_ANONYMOUS|MAP_PRIVATE, fd, 0);
  if (addr2 == MAP_FAILED)
    handle_error("mmap");
  printf("second map: 0x%tx\n", addr2);

  // test whether the memory is still available
  p = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int)*10);
  printf("allocated address: 0x%tx\n", p);

  return 0;
}
```

**Output:**

```
page size = 4096
start = 0x1d77000
first map: 1d77000
second map: 0x7f5f26c2f000
allocated address: 0x1d76030
```

Comment: Why do you want to do that? What problem would that solve?

Comment: And how do you know (or care) where physically the virtual memory page will reside?

Comment: Mat: I suppose it would tickle pointer truncation bugs quicker!

Comment: concur duskwuff. As the library was initially windows 32-bit and ported to windows 64-bit, then ported to Linux 32-bit and 64-bit.

Comment: So the real question was about a good tool to help finding memory leaks: `valgrind`

Comment: This question is about finding pointer arithmetic errors. Common examples are casting an unsigned 64bit pointer to a 32bit integer, comparing a pointer value to a signed integer, or using bits 63 or 31 as sentinel flags. These are all things that worked in 32bit code but will fail when ported to 64bit. The OP wishes to create a test version of their application that is very likely to crash if these mistakes have been made.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't understand **why you want to do that** (avoiding `mmap` giving some address in the first four gigabytes).

Hoever, you could, very early in your program -e.g. start of `main`, or even some constructor function- call [mmap(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mmap.2.html) with `MAP_FIXED` and `MAP_NORESERVE` on several memory segments to achieve your goal; so you would ensure that all the address space below 4G would be "filled" -either by pre-existing segments of your programs, or by your such calls to `mmap`.

However, your library (which could be indirectly `dlopen`-ed) could be started much after the program.

Once the first four gigabytes are used in the address spaces, most ordinary `mmap` calls (those done by `malloc` for example) would go outside.

Of course, you should `mmap` *at some time before* the first `malloc` (which would probably call `mmap` or `sbrk`); and you should take care of the existing memory segments (perhaps you can get them by parsing `/proc/self/maps`), because you need to avoid them in your `mmap` `MAP_FIXED|MAP_NORESERVE`.

And you could also define your own `malloc`. Perhaps you could `mmap` with `MAP_NORESERVE` a huge region (e.g. a terabyte), and have your own `malloc` using only address inside (by `mmap`-ing again there).

<sup>I think you are trying to solve the wrong problem. Doing what I suggest could be tricky... I see no valid reason to avoid addresses in the first 4 Gbytes.</sup>

BTW, a good tool to find memory leaks on Linux is [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/).

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I tried but another problem I hit was: how you specify the _addr_ passed into _mmap()_, as we are going to use MAP_FIXED?

Comment: It is up to you to find out. I don't have the source code of your program. The *addr* should be non-null, page aligned.

Comment: I've created a sample code (please see the original post) and the output. I was hoping after the first mmap, the memory should be reserved and malloc should pick the memory after the first mmap. But it still uses mem before it. Maybe the way of getting start addr is wrong?

Comment: It is more complex than that. I edited my reply accordingly. I really want to know why are you asking..... My feeling is that you are trying to *solve another problem* (which we cannot guess). **Why do you ask your question?**

Comment: Thank you again, and as I posted above, the library is being ported from 32-bit to 64-bit on Linux. We used top-down memory allocation on Windows to discover some bugs. I am hoping to do the similar test on Linux.

Comment: You just want `valgrind` and should have simply searched some tool to find memory leaks....